# Docker nginx ssl error

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker, docker-compose

When I raise the container, I get the following errors:

```
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx    | 2022/09/04 23:08:42 [emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/ssl/5master.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/5master.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx    | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/ssl/5master.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/5master.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx exited with code 1
```

Although in the DockerFile, I copied the certificate files that are in the command invocation folder.

nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         5master.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/5master.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/5master.key;
}
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY 5master.crt /etc/ssl/5master.crt
COPY 5master.key /etc/ssl/5master.key
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: run.py
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app


  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /application/static/:/static
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the certificate files and the nginx config in the `api` container. You need to mount the files in the `nginx` container as volumes instead.

```
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /application/static/:/static
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
      - ./5master.crt:/etc/ssl/5master.crt
      - ./5master.key:/etc/ssl/5master.key
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```